# Iterating over a temporary std::initializer_list with range based for

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, undefined-behavior, compiler-bug

Given this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <string>

int a, b;

int main() {
    for (auto p : std::initializer_list<std::pair<int &, std::string>>{
        { a, "a" },
        { b, "b" },
    })
    {
        std::cout << p.second << ": " << p.first << '\n';
    }
}
```

I expect the output

```
a: 0
b: 0
```

and [gcc](http://rextester.com/AON96829) and [clang](http://rextester.com/MIIC62257) agree, however, [Visual Studio](http://rextester.com/MBDBIH74026) 2013 Update 5 (my version, not sure what rextester uses) disagrees and prints this:

```
: 0
: 0
```

Visual Studio had an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924358) with `std::initializer_list`, but it is supposed have been fixed since update 2.

Is this a bug in Visual Studio or am I invoking undefined or unspecified behavior?

Comment: I believe this is a bug, I reported it on connect at the time and it has been fixed since, but I don't recall if in an update or in 2015. [my test case from back then](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/247271563/whyyy.png)

Comment: @NathanOliver cannot repro, works with 2015 for me.

Comment: @melak47 I am not sure what I did but I retested it and it works on my machine now.  I deleted my misleading comment.  thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

From the "Explanation" section on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), a range-for loop is equivalent to :

```
{
    auto && __range = range_expression ;
    for (auto __begin = begin_expr,
                __end = end_expr;
            __begin != __end;
            ++__begin) {
        range_declaration = *__begin;
        loop_statement
    }
}
```

You can see that the iterated range (`range_epxression`) is bound to a forwarding reference. In your case the latter turns into an rvalue reference, since your `initializer_list` is a temporary, and its lifetime is thus extended to the whole `for` loop.

MSVC is wrong here.

Comment: Isn't `auto &&` actually called a forwarding reference or is that only when it is a template?

Comment: @NathanOliver `auto` behaves like template argument deduction, so it is indeed a forwarding reference, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

from cppreference.com:

> The underlying array is not guaranteed to exist after the lifetime of the original initializer list object has ended. The storage for std::initializer_list is unspecified (i.e. it could be automatic, temporary, or static read-only memory, depending on the situation).   (until C++14)
>
> The underlying array is a temporary array, in which each element is copy-initialized (except that narrowing conversions are invalid) from the corresponding element of the original initializer list. The lifetime of the underlying array is the same as any other temporary object, except that initializing an initializer_list object from the array extends the lifetime of the array exactly like binding a reference to a temporary (with the same exceptions, such as for initializing a non-static class member). The underlying array may be allocated in read-only memory. (since C++14)

From this I would infer that the compiler is in error since the lifetime of the initializer_list should end after the closing brace.